# Declare (min-/max-)width/height of elements directly or use 100% and inheritance from outside

Tags: html, css, inheritance, height

This [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/junior87/qqQyy/) shows a very basic version of the markup I have. I want the `.module-container`'s to resize between 230px (min-height) and 300px (max-height). Basically what I like to know is whether to set the min-/max-height on the `.row` and giving the `.module-container`'s a `height: 100%;` or explicitly give each `.module-container` a (min-/max-)height as well as a height of 100% and the containing `.row` just wraps around it like so

```
min-height: 14.375em; /* 230px, 1em=16px */
height: 100%;
max-height: 18.75em; /* 300px, 1em=16px */
```

What I expect is that the div grows in between 230px and 300px. But does that work when the containing `.row` container has no explicit height and thus wraps around each `.column`?

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/qqQyy/2/ The cols always have a minimum height of 230px (as you see left), and stretch with content to 300px. If it has more content, that is clipped (as you see right).

Comment: The thing with the floated cols is that I can't make them the same height (e.g. min < 100% < max). They should be all the same height. Your example does not resize at all using chrome.

Comment: Well, it does. But they resize depending on content, and I suspect that you're looking for some other resize. You have to consider that height is determined by content or when explicitly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it on the `.module-container`. There's no need to set `height: 100%;` because any `block` level element will expand to wrap its inner elements.

Answer (score 0):

Block elements can have `% height` when its parent element has height property.

`html`, `body`, `div.row`, and all of the other parent elements have to be set to `height:100%` or it's own height value.